# How to reconstruct the original data when using manifold learning?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, nonlinear, manifold-learning

I'm using Isomap to reduce the dimensionality of my data.

Isomap use geodesic distance rather than Euclidean distance to perform a MDS.

Now I want to reconstruct my original data with a lower dimensional coordinate. How can I do that?

When the lower dimensional coordinate lies on a data point, things could be easy. Just perform a certain kind of trace back. But what if it lies out of data points?